# ServiceStack cache in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, servicestack

How do I go about implementing ServiceStack cache in VB.net? I've seen many C# examples, but I am not able to transfer this onto vb.net.

The point I get stack in the 1st and 2nd argument of the `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RequestContextExtensions.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache`

- 1st should be: `ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IRequestContext` - not sure
  what IRequestContext is
- 2nd should be:
  `ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Providers.MemoryCacheClient` - how do I set
  this do cache default in config i.e. MemoryCacheClient

Code below, any suggestion much appreciated.

**Global.asax.vb**

```
Public Class Global_asax
     Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

     Public Class HelloAppHost
          Inherits AppHostBase

          Public Sub New()
               MyBase.New("Web Services", GetType(Wrapper).Assembly)
          End Sub

          Public Overrides Sub Configure(ByVal container As Container)

               Routes.Add(Of GetProduct)("/GetProduct").Add(Of GetProduct)("/GetProduct/{*}")

               Plugins.Add(New Cors.CorsFeature(allowedHeaders:="Content-Type, Authorization"))
               container.Register(Of ICacheClient)(New MemoryCacheClient())

          End Sub

     End Class


     Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

          Dim apphost = New HelloAppHost()
          apphost.Init()

     End Sub

End Class
```

**WS.vb**

```
Public Class Wrapper

    Public Class WrapperGetProduct
        Implements IService(Of GetProduct)
        Public Function Execute(ByVal request As GetProduct) As Object Implements ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService(Of GetProduct).Execute

            Dim cachekey As String = "some_key"
            Dim expireInTimespan = New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)

            Return ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RequestContextExtensions.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
                ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IRequestContext,  // not sure what this should be
                ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Providers.MemoryCacheClient,  // not sure what this should be - how do I set this to cache setted in configuration (in memory cache)?
                cachekey, expireInTimespan, 
                Function() request.HandleRequest()
            )


        End Function
    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [new API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api)

`ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` is an extension method for `RequestContext` which services inherit/expose, same with Cache (resolved automatically via IOC).

Example below converted from C#, caching/wrapping an existing service (AppConfig and Repository are resolved via IOC, registered in AppHost configure method).

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports ServiceStack.Common
Imports ServiceStack.ServiceHost
Imports ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel
Imports ServiceStack.Common.Web

Public Class SearchTerm

    Public Property Latitude() As Double
        Get
            Return m_Latitude
        End Get
        Set
            m_Latitude = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Latitude As Double

    Public Property Longitude() As Double
        Get
            Return m_Longitude
        End Get
        Set
            m_Longitude = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Longitude As Double

    Public Property Term() As String
        Get
            Return m_Term
        End Get
        Set
            m_Term = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Term As String

End Class

<Route("/lookup/searchterm", "GET")> _
Public Class SearchTermRequest
    Implements IReturn(Of SearchTermResponse)

    Public Property Term() As String
        Get
            Return m_Term
        End Get
        Set
            m_Term = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Term As String

End Class

Public Class SearchTermResponse
    Implements IHasResponseStatus

    Public Property ResponseStatus() As ResponseStatus
        Get
            Return m_ResponseStatus
        End Get
        Set
            m_ResponseStatus = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ResponseStatus As ResponseStatus

    Public Property Results() As List(Of SearchTerm)
        Get
            Return m_Results
        End Get
        Set
            m_Results = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Results As List(Of SearchTerm)

End Class

<Route("/cached/lookup/searchterm")> _
Public Class CachedSearchTermRequest
    Implements IReturn(Of CachedSearchTermResponse)

    Public ReadOnly Property CacheKey() As String
        Get
            Return UrnId.Create(Of CachedSearchTermRequest)(String.Format("{0}", Me.Term))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Term() As String
        Get
            Return m_Term
        End Get
        Set
            m_Term = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Term As String

End Class

Public Class CachedSearchTermResponse
    Implements IHasResponseStatus

    Public Property ResponseStatus() As ResponseStatus
        Get
            Return m_ResponseStatus
        End Get
        Set
            m_ResponseStatus = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ResponseStatus As ResponseStatus

    Public Property Results() As List(Of SearchTerm)
        Get
            Return m_Results
        End Get
        Set
            m_Results = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Results As List(Of SearchTerm)

End Class

Public Class SearchTermService
    Inherits Service

    Public Property Repository() As IRepository
        Get
            Return m_Repository
        End Get
        Set
            m_Repository = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Repository As IRepository

    Public Function [Get](request As SearchTermRequest) As SearchTermResponse
            Return New SearchTermResponse() With { _
                Key .Results = Me.Repository.SearchTermGet(request) _
            }
    End Function

End Class

Public Class CachedSearchTermService
    Inherits Service

    Public Property AppConfig() As AppConfig
        Get
            Return m_AppConfig
        End Get
        Set
            m_AppConfig = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_AppConfig As AppConfig

    Public Function [Get](request As CachedSearchTermRequest) As Object
        Dim cacheKey As String = request.CacheKey
        Return Me.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
            MyBase.Cache, cacheKey, New TimeSpan(0, Me.AppConfig.CacheTimeMinutes, 0),
                Function() 
                    Using service = Me.ResolveService(Of SearchTermService)()
                        Return service.[Get](request.TranslateTo(Of SearchTermRequest)()).TranslateTo(Of CachedSearchTermResponse)()
                    End Using
               End Function
            )
    End Function

End Class
```